# How does Chainlink deal with faulty/malicious nodes?

Tags: solidity, oracles, chainlink

I am trying to understand how chainlink, or any oracle solution for that matter, can deal with a node not providing accurate data. How would you detect that the data is faulty to begin with, and how would you "punish" the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All oracle networks don't necessarily take the same approach, however as the most used oracle network with a high focus on security and reliability, Chainlink specifically [looks for outlier results](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/external-adapters-js/blob/ecd19d51e18dab480f313c8a128d794de7232c39/packages/composites/outlier-detection/README.md) ('faulty data'), and then takes appropriate action if any are found, to ensure the data feed isn't negatively affected.

In terms of penalties or 'punishment', Chainlink has [published](https://blog.chain.link/chainlink-staking-roadmap/) its roadmap and long term goals for crypto-economic staking. Suggest reading this for more info on how nodes will be kept honest. This is currently in development, with a target to go live later in the year